# How to sum from multiple tables with different structure?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Hi I am attempting to create a "Reputation" for a user's profile by using SQL query to sum up the 'likes' & 'amount' of awards and subtracting the amount of 'dislikes'

I can get the sum from one table but cannot get it to work correctly with multiple tables,

The table structures are different for both tables, I cannot find any questions that are the same as mine..

Here is my 1st table "articles"

| username | likes | dislikes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 3 | -1 |

Here is my 2nd table "awards"

| username | amount |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 3 |

**In this case it should output 5** but I can't get it to work

```
 SELECT SUM(rep) AS totalRep FROM 
  (
    SELECT `likes` FROM `articles` UNION ALL
    SELECT `dislikes` FROM `articles` UNION ALL
    SELECT `amount` FROM `awards` UNION ALL
  ) GROUP BY `username`
```

I have also tried like this..

```
SELECT SUM(rep) AS totalRep FROM 
  (
    SELECT SUM(likes) FROM `articles` UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(dislikes) FROM `articles` UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(amount) FROM `awards` UNION ALL
  ) GROUP BY `username`
```

and like this..

```
SELECT rep SUM(totrep) AS totrep FROM 
(
  SELECT likes,dislikes FROM `articles`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT amount FROM `awards`
) GROUP BY `username`
```

and..

```
SELECT SUM(likes,dislikes,amount) AS totrep
  FROM (
        SELECT likes,dislikes FROM `articles`
        UNION ALL
        SELECT amount FROM `awards`
       )  GROUP BY `username`
```

Comment: why there is pdo and PHP if your question is about mysql query? and you didn't put the only relevant tag

Comment: @kaoticode when asking an SQL question please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and update the question with relevant data.

Comment: @ErgestBasha I don't know how to ask the question any better than this, I have edited and added the tables properly and added what I have tried if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `articles` table you need to sum likes+dislikes and then use union all.

Try:

```
select username,sum(amount) as totalRep
FROM ( 
       select username,
              (sum(likes)+sum(dislikes)) as amount
       from articles
       group by username
    union all
       select username,
              amount
     from awards
     ) as t1
group by  username;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bee2cf836d5a7b76cea65e3b773e880c

Comment: Okay but how do I fetch the result? I am trying to use echo like so.. `<?php echo $rep['totalRep']; ?>` and what is `t1`? Also, does the column _need_ to be set as Int? or will it work with Varchar too? thanks for the response

Comment: Ah its okay, I got it working using your answer, thankyou! I had one `)` in the wrong place, is good now, thanks again!

Comment: @kaoticode t1 is just an alias for the subquery because Every derived table must have its own alias. `Also, does the column need to be set as Int?` Yes. To use sum( or any aggregation functions) the columns must be in [numeric](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-types.html) values, or you need to cast it